# How to always redirect to https://www and https://subdomain?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I want to redirect everything to URLs that start with `https://www` or `https://subdomain`. If it's a URL with no subdomain then I want it to always redirect to the `https://www` version. And if there is a non-www subdomain then I want it to always redirect to the `https://subdomain` version.

The first thing I had would just redirect everything to `https://www`. Here's that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I think the only problem with that is that it will redirect non-www subdomains to the multilevel `https://www.subdomain`. So then I added a second condition to the second rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.(.*)\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This appears to work for everything I want with one problem. If there is a subdomain and something after the domain like a directory then it won't work. For example this:

`sub.site.com`

will correctly redirect to:

`https://sub.site.com`

But this:

`sub.site.com/test/`

will not redirect to:

`https://sub.site.com/test/`

So why doesn't this last URL get rewritten when there is something after the domain like the /test/ directory?

Comment: Your rules in question should redirect `/test/` also. You might be having other rules or code issue.

Comment: Does `test/` also have a .htaccess?